# Merging two datasets by an ID without adding new columns that say ".x" or ".y"

Tags: r, merge

Suppose I have two datasets. One main dataset, with many columns of metadata, and one new dataset which will be used to fill in some of the gaps in concentrations in the main dataset:

Main dataset:

```
study_id  timepoint    age    occupation        concentration1   concentration2
1         1            21     0                 3                7
1         2            21     0                 4                6
1         3            22     0                 NA               NA
1         4            22     0                 NA               NA
2         1            36     3                 0                4
2         2            36     3                 2                11
2         3            37     3                 NA               NA
2         4            37     3                 NA               NA
```

New data set to merge:

```
study_id  timepoint    concentration1   concentration2
1         3            11               20
1         4            21               35
2         3             7               17
2         4            14               25
```

Whenever I merge by "study_id" and "timepoint", I get two new columns that are "concentration1.y" and "concentration2.y" while the original columns get renamed as "concentration1.x" and "concentration2.x". I don't want this.

This is what I want:

```
study_id  timepoint    age    occupation        concentration1   concentration2
1         1            21     0                 3                7
1         2            21     0                 4                6
1         3            22     0                 11               20
1         4            22     0                 21               35
2         1            36     3                 0                4
2         2            36     3                 2                11
2         3            37     3                 7                17
2         4            37     3                 14               25
```

In other words, I want to merge by "study_id" and "timepoint" AND merge the two concentration columns so the data are within the same columns. Please note that both datasets do not have identical columns (dataset 1 has 1000 columns with metadata while dataset2 just has study id, timepoint, and concentration columns that match the concentration columns in dataset1).

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `coalesce` is one option (from `dplyr` package). This still adds the two columns for concentration 1 and 2 from the second data frame. These would be removed after `NA` filled in.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("study_id", "timepoint")) %>%
  mutate(concentration1 = coalesce(concentration1.x, concentration1.y),
         concentration2 = coalesce(concentration2.x, concentration2.y)) %>%
  select(-concentration1.x, -concentration1.y, -concentration2.x, -concentration2.y)
```

Or to generalize with multiple `concentration` columns:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("study_id", "timepoint")) %>%
  split.default(str_remove(names(.), "\\.x|\\.y")) %>%
  map_df(reduce, coalesce)
```

**Edit**: To prevent the resultant column names from being alphabetized from `split.default`, you can add an intermediate step of sorting the list based on the first data frame's column name order.

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("study_id", "timepoint")) %>%
  split.default(str_remove(names(.), "\\.x|\\.y"))

df3[names(df1)] %>%
  map_df(reduce, coalesce)
```

**Output**

```
  study_id timepoint age occupation concentration1 concentration2
1        1         1  21          0              3              7
2        1         2  21          0              4              6
3        1         3  22          0             11             20
4        1         4  22          0             21             35
5        2         1  36          3              0              4
6        2         2  36          3              2             11
7        2         3  37          3              7             17
8        2         4  37          3             14             25
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(study_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    timepoint = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), age = c(21L, 
    21L, 22L, 22L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L), occupation = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), concentration1 = c(3L, 4L, NA, NA, 
    0L, 2L, NA, NA), concentration2 = c(7L, 6L, NA, NA, 4L, 11L, 
    NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(study_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), timepoint = c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L), concentration1 = c(11L, 21L, 7L, 14L), concentration2 = c(20L, 
35L, 17L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to have worked. You're a lifesaver. I have a follow-up question if you're able to answer. What if I have 100 concentrations? Is there a way to apply this to 100 columns instead of just 2 without writing out all the column names?

Comment: @DrWampa Please see edited answer, would this work?

Comment: Thank you so much. Almost there...  the only issue is that this reorders all the columns to be in alphabetical order instead of in the original order of df1... Your original solution didn't do this, so it seems to be the addition of map_df that's causing it... Any ideas of how to combat this? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Dr Wampa See edited answer. You can add an intermediate step and sort the list based on the column name order of `df1` before using `map_df`. See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ben! Solved!